# jquery form validate function not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, jquery-validate

I have noticed that when I do not have any validation messages indicating that there is a validation error my code is behaving as if there were validation errors.

Here is my jquery click function and inside it I want to make an ajax call if the form is validated:

```
  $("#otherFavContainer").on("click", ".btnAddSongTilesToGenre", function (e) {
        var name = $('#youTubeNameTxt').val();
        var link = $('#youTubeLinkTxt').val();
        var len = link.length;
        var substr = link.substr(31, len - 31);
        var container = $(this).parent().parent().find(".actualTilesContainer");
        $(container).slideDown();
        var genreId = $(this).attr("name");
        $("#hiddenRank").val(genreId);
        $("#AddTopTenFavForm").validate().form();

        if ($("#AddTopTenFavForm").valid()) {

            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function () { ShowAjaxLoader(); },
                url: "/Home/AddSong",
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#AddTopTenFavForm").serialize(),
                success: function (data) { HideAjaxLoader(), ShowMsg("Song Added Successfully"), $(container).find('ul').append('<li><a class="savedLinks" href="#" name="' + substr + '" >' + name + '</a> <span name= ' + data + ' class="btnDeleteSong dontDoAnything">x</span></li>'); },
                error: function () { HideAjaxLoader(), ShowMsg("Song could not be added, please try again") }
            });


            $('#youTubeLinkTxt').val('');
            $('#youTubeNameTxt').val('');

        }
        else {
            alert("notValid");
        }

        if ($(e.target).hasClass("dontDoAnything")) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In the if statement the code always goes to the else part displaying the alert message box.
I do not have any validation errors since no validation message appears.

Here is my validation logic:

```
 namespace yplaylist.Models
 {
[MetadataType(typeof(TopTenFav_Validation))]
public partial class TopTenFav
{

}
public class TopTenFav_Validation
{

[RegularExpression("http://www.youtube.com/watch\\?v=.*", ErrorMessage = "Youtube Link must begin with: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v= ")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Youtube link is Required")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage="Song Title cannot exceed 100 characters")]
public string YoutubeLink { get; set; }

[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Youtube link cannot exceed 100 characters")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Song title is Required")]
public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

}

I doublecheck that I input data in a correct format into my textboxes and everything seems ok but my form is still not valid for some strange reason, please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `$("#AddTopTenFavForm").valid()` to see what it returns.

Comment: alert is the simplest and dirty way to do it. If you are using Firebug plugin for Firefox or Chrome you can open the console and check there.

    if(window.console)
        window.console.log($("#AddTopTenFavForm").valid())